# Can't find listener for bar icon

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an app that, thought the method `setHomeAsUpIndicator`, replaces the title of the activity. So far everything makes sense because it can be understood by reading the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setHomeAsUpIndicator(int)), but I can't figure out why, when I press the icon, a certain Activity is launched. 
This specific part of the code looks like this:

```
private void myMethod() {
  actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
  actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(
    ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.someIcon)
  );
  actionBar.setHomeActionContentDescription(
    getResources().getString(R.string.correspondingDescription)
  );
  actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
}
```

When `someIcon` is pressed, another Activity is launched, but I don't know where is that indicated.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It moves to previous activity because there is a parent activity set in a AndroidManifest.xml file, like this :

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ExampleActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity"/>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Is there any way to change it's behavior?? (Make a listener)

Comment: Yes, you can override one method in activity, which shown in link below

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37401287/how-to-add-a-listener-for-the-up-button-in-actionbar-on-android